# Configure ssh keys for github actions?

Tags: git, github-actions, pre-commit.com

I'm using a custom [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hook that's in a private repo.

```
  - repo: git@github.com:username/precommit-hooks.git
    rev: v0.0.1
    hooks:
      - id: check-security
```

I run it in a github action

```
      - name: Run pre-commit on changed files
        run: |
          pip install pre-commit
          pre-commit run --from-ref origin/HEAD --to-ref HEAD
```

But it errors for credential failure, but shouldn't [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) `persist-credentials`?

> The auth token is persisted in the local git config. This enables your scripts to run authenticated git commands. The token is removed during post-job cleanup. Set persist-credentials: false to opt-out.

```
[INFO] Initializing environment for git@github.com:homer/precommit-hooks.git.
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/bin/git', 'fetch', 'origin', '--tags')
return code: 128
stdout: (none)
stderr:
    git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

What's a good way to configure SSH creds?

Answer (score 1):

**if you're cloning over `ssh` you will need to have an `ssh` key**

the `persist-credentials` are for the repository under test (and are a short-lived github app token **not** an ssh token) -- the very same that's present in `${{ github.token }}` or `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

if you need an ssh key, you'll need to set one up and add it, probably through a github actions secret

here's an (untested) idea -- (I adapted this from a gpg-based secret) -- I don't think you need the public key but if you do you could utilize the same approach:

```
        install --directory ~/.ssh --mode 700
        base64 -d <<< '${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE }}' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

then store the secret as a base64'd secret

---

another approach would be to utilize `insteadOf` to rewrite ssh urls to https urls the proper credentials attached -- though I haven't done that so you'd have to figure that out

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit, though in fairness this problem has nothing to do with pre-commit

Comment: i like these suggestions, I will try, thank you @anthony for taking the time to look at this